# Find Position of hand from X axis after k seconds

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Let center of minute hand of clock be at (0,0) and its endpoint at (0,m) 
After 1 second, y coordinate of endpoint is h units above X axis. 
What will be y coordinate of minute hand after k seconds(where k can be large)

Note: Minute hand doesn't rotate by 2π/3600 each second but by different fixed angle

Comment: Does the minute hand move at a constant angular velocity? If not, then I don't see a way to answer this.

Comment: Yes, it moves with constant angular velocity

Comment: This is taken from a live programming contest: https://www.codechef.com/FEB18/problems/BROCLK